# SQL query executed in RDS via a sql client executes instantly when same query executed via Lambda is running forever?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I have a RDS view which has medium complexity.
Problem is I am getting intermittent timeout error when I do a select * from view via a Lambda (python) but when i do the same in DBeaver (a sql client), the result is returned instantly.

Few notes:

1. I checked the IOPS balance in RDS and it was consistently at 99%, so there is no issue.
2. Same view returning data instantly in a sql client, so may be issue with RDS - Lambda connectivity?
3. But same connectivity is used by other Lambdas to the same RDS instance, and
   they all connect and do their work successfully.
4. Upon checking the metadata tables, that select * from view is shown as Active query
   logged in database, so its not that the query returned the result but Lambda didn't received it.
5. The job cadence is daily but the timeout is like once a week or so.

99% of times, a simple re-execution of the lambda works but sometimes, we need to manually execute the query in sql client and fetch the result.

pg_stat_Activity output:

> [image]

**Edit:**
I checked the RDS performance insights and there the executed query is shown running for couple of hours. At this point, I believe it to be a query issue only.
Still during the original query which was executed via lambda, if i execute the same query in client, it gets successfully executed within seconds.
I need to find a way to check where exactly the query is stuck .

Below is the snapshot from RDS, the smaller spikes you see on top of the larger plateau are the other queries which ran and finished without any intervention.
[image]

Comment: You'll need to get some logs so you have some facts to work with - at least you'll want to see if the lambda connects and the query gets run.

Comment: Feels vaguely like something I had which turned out to be transaction isolation levels. Is there anything that specifies txn isolation in your Lambda or *other apps accessing the db* ? (If everything is using Postgres default txn isolation then it's probably _not_ that).

Comment: @RichardHuxton yes the lambda got connected as the query which is written in the lambda (select *), i can find in the active queries in RDS. I checked in cloudwatch and lambda is able to make connection to RDS via psycopg, use that connection to send the query (via cursor.execute) and then just waits for the response for ~15 minutes.

Comment: OK, so the next thing is to find out how long the query is actually taking and if it is getting an odd plan. You can turn on duration logging and add in auto_explain in a regular PostgreSQL setup but I've no idea what limitations Amazon impose on your setup.

Comment: @RichardHuxton Upon encountering the failure, i went into RDS and checked the pg_stat_Activity. Added the data in the question. Also , at that time, the query was still running , so i went ahead and fired the same query via DBeaver and it gave the result in 1-2 secs.

Comment: The activity view isn't going to show anything useful I'm afraid. You know what the query is. The difference can only really be caused by (1) different query plan (2) locks or (3) network. I don't see how it can be locks if you can repeat the query and it completes. You will need to compare a query plan for a slow call with a fast one. One way to test the network is to schedule a second lambda at the same time that just fetches a bunch of rows about the same size (use `generate_series()` or something - anything to create about the same amount of data as your slow query).

Comment: @RichardHuxton first of all, thanks for being here on this for me.
Yeah there are no locks as during the execution from lambda, i did check, though again from stat activity, using pg_blocking_pids(pid) and there were none. Also, another thing is this lambda is 1 out of 20 or so which runs 1 by 1 during that time and evrytime this failure has occurred (3-4 times in last month) is in this particular lambda and this particular view.

Answer (score 1):

DBeaver (by default) doesn't select all the rows up front.  It uses something like a cursor, to fetch only the number of rows it needs for the first few pages.

Comment: yes and i have only 5-10 rows as the output.

Comment: That does make it less likely, but it still might lead to a different plan being used.